# An elegant way of handling click and keypress in the same function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a bunch of places where I have to code the same functionality for a click and an <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key press (keyup). I'm ending up writing event handlers like this:

```
$('#SomeElement').on('click keyup', function (e) {
  if (e.type === 'click' || e.type === 'keyup' && e.keyCode === 13) {
    //  do what needs to be done
  }
});
```

Is there an elegant way of handling this without the `if` statement?  I hate the fact that it's an event handler specific to `click` and `keyup`, yet I have to check the event type inside the handler.

**EDIT:**  I'm OK with abstracting out the `if` statement into a separate function.  As long as I don't have to copy/paste the same line of code over and over again.

Comment: e.type === 'click' || e.keyCode === 13

Comment: You could use the corollary and return / exit the function when the condition is true:  ` e.type === 'keyup' && e.keyCode !== 13`  //else do something

Comment: @devlincarnate I could, but I still have to write an "if" statement.

Comment: @Dimskiy : you're not going to get around that.

Comment: @AvcS you should post that as an answer. It's infinitely better than what's been posted so far.

Comment: Does anyone else feel that the community here has been draining down the toilet for the past few years?  Why is everything downvoted?  What's wrong with my question?  Is it not legitimate?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My final solution - [jQuery Event Extensions](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-extensions/).

Create jQuery event extension specific for ENTER key.

```
$.event.special.enterkey = {
    delegateType: 'keyup',
    bindType: 'keyup',
    handle: function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 13)
            return event.handleObj.handler.apply(this, arguments);
    }
};
```

Now all I have to do is the following.  Neat and elegant.

```
$('#SomeElement').on('click enterkey', function (e) {
    //  do what needs to be done
});
```

P.S. To all the incognito downvoters - you should be ashamed of yourselves.

Answer (score 2):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

(function( $ ) {
 
    $.fn.clickOrKeyPress = function( callback ) {

      this.on('click keyup', function (e) {

        if (e.type === 'click' || e.type === 'keyup' && e.keyCode === 13) {
          callback(e);
        }
          
      });
 
        return this;

    };
 
}( jQuery ));
```

Comment: I ended up with my own solution, but you pushed me in the right direction with extensions.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You will need an if condition to confirm if the key pressed is enter. So you cannot completely get rid of if condition there.

But you can get rid of redundant conditions, like you don't need to check if the event type is `keyup` as we know  if the event is not `click`, it will definitely be a `keyup` event.

So you can reduce your condition to

```
e.type === 'click' || e.keyCode === 13
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this yet, but maybe you can do named function and pass it with another callback to the event handler?...

Example (not tested!):

```js
// Define the callback function somewhere
function clickKeyupCallback(e, callback) {
  if (e.type === 'click' || e.type === 'keyup' && e.keyCode === 13) {
        return callback;
  }
}



$('#SomeElement').on('click keyup', clickKeyUpCallback(e, function() {
  // your normal code here
  
  
}));
```

// EDIT

I realized the named function has to sit on a different place here if you want to do it this way and abstract the "if" part.

another example:

```js
// Define the callback function somewhere
function clickKeyupCallback(e, callback) {
  if (e.type === 'click' || e.type === 'keyup' && e.keyCode === 13) {
    callback();
  }
}


$('#SomeElement').on('click keyup', function(e) {
  clickKeyupCallback(e, function() {
    // do what ever needs to be done

  });
});
```

Comment: Let me give this a try - might actually be a pretty good idea.

Comment: This is just an overcomplicated abstraction. There's no real difference here.

Comment: well, besides it being wrong. `e` isn't defined there.

Comment: I added another example. Of course not the preferred way here, but it would solve repeating the if checkup for him here, so in this case the abstraction is in the first place not really complicated at all and in the second place it is outsourcing in a way the "main checkup" before running the work after the if. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand clearly what you mean by "I have a bunch of places where I have to code the same functionality". But according to my understanding you want to attach some handlers to some elements that involve this check.

```
function doSomething(e) {
  //do what needs to be done
}

function handleEvent(attachedHandler) {
  return function(e) {
     if (e.type === 'click' || e.type === 'keyup' && e.keyCode === 13) {
      attachedHandler(e);
     } 
   };
}

$('#SomeElement').on('click keyup', handleEvent(doSomething));
```

lemme know if it helps you...

Comment: hm why it is downvoted. I clearly didn't understand the stack over flow community. What is wrong with this answer. Any pointers??

Comment: DV isn't mine but this doesn't change anything. It's an abstraction of the `if` stattement to hide it away in another (unnecessary) function.

Comment: But didn't this is what the OP wants. To not have to repeat the same `if` again. Clearly If one is attaching two events to the same handler an `if` is needed to differentiate between them.

Comment: Well firstly, they don't want the `if` at all. Secondly, the original requires one `if` statement and this still requires the same one `if` statement. Nothing has changed except needing more code.

Comment: Then in that case he/she needs one handler per event. But from the question, I think the OP wants the abstraction of the `if` statement. But in either way, I didn't understand why my answer is down voted by someone. (what a brutal response).